# How to work with a generic map whose key and values belong to a certain hierarchy?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

My objective is to create a Map whose keys are Class instances and whose values are instances of the corresponding Class. Meaning,

Map (a certain class in a hierarchy --> its corresponding instance)

To do that, I declared Map like

```
Map<Class<? extends BaseService>, ? extends BaseService> serviceMap = 
    new HashMap<Class<? extends BaseService>, BaseService>();
//Assume BaseService is at the root of hierarchy.
```

The above compiles.

In order to populate the Map, I used

```
public <T extends BaseService> void register(T service) {   
    serviceMap.put(service.getClass(), service);    
}
```

This does not compile.

How do I make this work ? And why doesn't this compile ?

Comment: would be nice to see an error message of your compiler

Comment: The method put(Class<? extends BaseService>, capture#1-of ? extends BaseService) in the type Map<Class<? extends BaseService>,capture#1-of ? extends BaseService> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#2-of ? extends BaseService>, T)

Comment: FYI, you're more or less reinventing [Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [`ClassToInstanceMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html), though that already has nice type-safety things built into it.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Answer (score 5):

Your use of wildcards isn't exactly consistent with your English definition.  When you define:

```
Map<Class<? extends BaseService>, ? extends BaseService> serviceMap;
```

this might be described as "`serviceMap` is a map from Classes which extend `BaseService`, to *some type* of value (which is `BaseService` or a subclass)".

The compiler is correct to reject your `register` method in this context.  `serviceMap`'s value type is declared to be simply "something" - so you could easily assign a map to it with a value type of `ServiceImplOne`.  And your register method could be called with an argument of class `ServiceImplTwo`.  You can't insert this into the map as it's not consistent with the generic parameters!

It's clear that since you want to be able to insert any type of service, the map must accept **all instances of `BaseService`** as values, not *some* (unknown) subtype of BaseService.  Therefore you can fix this by declaring the map with a concrete value type:

```
Map<Class<? extends BaseService>, BaseService> serviceMap;
```