# How to define a Map whose key and value is enforced to have a related hierarchy?

Tags: java, generics, hierarchy

I have a root class called Entity. I also have service classes that do CRUD operations on a subtypes of Entity. So, my service class definitions follow this pattern

```
class Entity { 
   //the root class
}

class Service<T extends Entity> {
  //root service class containing common CRUD operations
}


class SomeEntity extends Entity {
}

class SomeService extends Service<SomeEntity> {
}
```

I maintain a Map of Entity class --> to their corresponding Service like

```
Map<Class<? extends Entity>, Service<? extends Entity>> = serviceMap
 new HashMap<Class<? extends Entity>, Service<? extends Entity>>();
```

However, the above doesn't enforce that the class and its corresponding Service belong to the same hierarchy. Hence, even after casting, my client code have to cast it again. How to avoid the following ? And enforce a strict relation among the key and value ?

```
    public <T extends Entity> Service<T> get(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (Service<T>) serviceMap.get(clazz);
    }

    //example of client code
    SomeService service = (SomeService) serviceRegistry.get(SomeEntity.class);
```

Comment: Is there always a 1:1 mapping between the entities and services? Or is there a need for an entity to use one service at a given point of time, but a different service later - at which time you would update the map?

Comment: Possible (near) duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720065/how-to-work-with-a-generic-map-whose-key-and-values-belong-to-a-certain-hierarch?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do what you'd like to do. It just isn't possible!

However, you shouldn't really need to know what the `Service` implementation is though. `Service` should define provide all the necessary methods for the client code to invoke. Hello polymorphism! Personally, I'd just change your get method slightly to:

```
Service<? extends Entity> getService(Class<?> entityClass) {
  return serviceMap.get(entityClass);
}
```

Client code shouldn't care too much about the actual implementation:

```
Service<? extends Entity> service = getService(SomeEntity.class);
service.save(myEntity);
```

Another option is if you know what the entity type is when you want the service then you can pass in the `Service` class and use that for the cast, eg:

```
<T extends Service<? extends Entity>> T getService(Class<?> entityClass, Class<T> serviceClass) {
  return serviceClass.cast(serviceMap.get(entityClass));
}
```

Admittedly, neither of the above methods guarantee that `SomeEntity.class` is paired with a SomeService instance in the `Map`.